# Best practice to test propTypes with jest + enzyme + react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have tried many solutions I found on google to test if `Component.propTypes` was set properly at a react component, but none of them worked for me. Even though I get a console warning when running my React application on the browser if the properties are passed incorrectly, when I run jest I can't capture that warning in any way that I tried. Here is my best attempt:

App.js:

```
export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <div/>;
    }
}


App.propTypes = {
    images: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {images} = state;
    return {images: images};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import sinon from 'sinon'

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';

const expect = chai.use(chaiEnzyme()).expect
const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

const wrap = (initialState, props) => {
    return shallow(<Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}><App {...props} /></Provider>)
};

describe('App container', () => {
    it('validates properties', () => {
        const stub = sinon.stub(console, 'warn');

        console.warn.reset();
        React.createElement(App, {});
        expect(stub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
        expect(stub.calledWithMatch(/Failed prop type/)).to.equal(true);

        console.warn.restore();
    });

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        wrap();
    });

    it('is react-redux connected', () => {
        const wrapper = wrap();
        expect(wrapper.find('Connect(App)')).to.have.length(1);
    });

    it('correctly maps properties', () => {
        const wrapper = wrap({images: []});
        expect(wrapper.props().images).to.equal([]);
    });
});
```

Comment: check if [jest-prop-type-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-prop-type-error) can help

Answer (score -1):

According to what I've read online on various GitHub issue threads, it seems like a common approach is to make `console.warn/console.error` throw.

So when you are writing your tests you can do something like

```
expect(// Render Component //).to.throw();
```

Hope this helps.

More info: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/588